# QT5 Creator "/usr/bin/g++" is used by qmake, but "/usr/bin/g++-9" is configured in the kit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In QT5 Creator, I changed the compiler version in the project kit, but it's throwing the above error now(note: 'g++' in this context refers to version 10, which QT5 isn't compatible with). I found *some* information on using terminal commands to change some stuff with qmake, but does anyone know how I can fix this?

Edit: To clarify, a kit different from the default kit is being used for this project(that's what I changed), and I'm migrating this project from QT4 to QT5. This is installed on Ubuntu, and there aren't multiple versions of QT on here(installed from Ubuntu repositories)

Comment: I tried to set the compiler to g++-9, g++-10, clang-9, but my (empty) project worked with them. Did you add a new kit, or modified the default kit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099731/g-is-used-by-qmake-and-gcc-is-configured-by-the-kit check this answer